# Visual Studio and GIT branch switch causes c1xx error for new files

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio

I have 2 GIT branches. 1)Master Branch and 2)Dev Branch.I usually work on the dev branch and at the end merge it into the master which is compiled  for the final release build.Everything is good as long as in the Dev branch there are no new files.If I add a new class into Dev branch,when I switch back to the Master branch and try to compile I am receiving errors like this:

```
error C1083: Cannot open source file 'somepath/tosource.cpp':
No such file or directory c1xx
```

It is strange because I made sure there files do not exist physically in the Master branch.So it means VS somehow keeps history of these from the dev branch?How can I clean it up so I don't need sync two branches every time I add new files into the dev branch?

Comment: I imagine VS has state stored in some sort of project files; therefore I'd imagine you need to keep these version-controlled too.  Otherwise its state won't change when you switch to a different Git branch.

Comment: Hmm..You mean I need to add .proj files into the repo?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you running? Are you remembering to commit your files before you switch branches? If you don't, you may be leaving untracked files behind in your working copy, so if you add new files to your dev branch and don't commit them, they'll still be in your working copy when you switch to the master branch, which could possibly give you the compilation error that you see above, because the new files reference source files that don't exist in master.

Comment: @Cupcake Running 2012 .Sure I commit.GIT even doesn't allow switching branches without commit.